# Why does the mirror pick up the image of the TV when the TV is not facing the mirror?

Tags: optics, reflection

Here is a picture of the problem: [image: mirror and TV]

Why is the mirror reflecting the TV screen when the TV screen is not facing the mirror?

Comment: it is "facing" the mirror: starting from the camera's eye move toward the TV's reflection in the mirror, when you hit the mirror turn toward the TV and you will see it looking back at you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: TV reflection.]

Just imagine looking from above, as schematised above and see the rays from the television being reflected by the wall mirror and into your eye.